# What are some existing or ideas where the use of a password can be replaced to login to a service?

Tags: authentication, passwords, multi-factor, account-security

The password has been a method of authentication for a long time now and we always hear of breaches happening where users passwords get stolen and sometimes are not even hashed at all or correctly. Plus there are loads of other problems with people using the password like reuse, too simple or brute forcing etc.

So my question is what are some ideas where we can replace the process of using a password to logon to a service or application? I know we have 2FA but I'm interested in either existing or future ideas to completely replace the password for the user.

A good example of what I'm on about which is sort of an alternative is typing DNA: https://www.typingdna.com/ But it still uses the idea of a password for the user.

I think the idea is to make it as simple and convenient as the password but more secure and easy for the user to still use as a login method.

Comment: A great idea would be if you could replace the idea of the user using a password but some service which can integrate by using a password still, therefore being able to work with any login which uses a password. Which is most apps these days.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be biometric authentication (e.g. fingerprint). This is a bad idea in a lot of cases. Primarily not because you finger might be damaged or someone uses it in some unsafe way but because if your secret (fingerprint) gets oublicly known: You will have the heck of a hard time changing it.

Another option would be temporary passwords. For example you enter your username and the service sends you a sms that you will be required to enter. Its like 2nd factor but as a first factor. It can also be a lot more elegant e.g. you will be requested by an app on you mobile device to tap a button and this simply authorizes your session in a web client on another machine.

A different option would be authentication via email. In this case a service generates an unique email adress (mail-auth-172adj289hf09ue2h9j8@yourdomain.com) that the user has to send a mail to using a special adress or containing a special string.

Basicly every 2nd factor could be used as a first factor. Like a hardware token that is plugged in or generates offline keys for you.

Comment: Yes, I did have an idea where Private & Public keys could be used, the login service/ API has your public key and a mobile app has the private key and you just tap a button to say yes you requested to logon but I'm not sure how many people would adopt such a service.

Comment: Depends. If everybody is required to use the app anyways so they have it already its most likely a good idea. Otherwise an SMS-Service might be better.

Comment: Yes, because everyone has a phone these days, so it makes sense to use the phone like a car key but for logging in. But then you have the problem of getting services like this site or FB, Twitter or Twitch to adopt your login service which could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a number of ways that something other than a password can be used. They all fall under the umbrella of methods to Authenticate.

The main ones are something you are, something you have, something you know, something you do, and somewhere you are. I'll explain each one below in a little more detail.

#### Something you are

This is where biometrics come into play, eg. Fingerprint scanner, iris readers, facial recognition, etc. etc. Basically things to do with your body.

#### Something you have

Something you have includes things like smart cards, yubikeys, rfid chips, basically anything physical that you own or have on your person.

#### Something you know

This is the traditional method of authentication, so things like pin numbers, passwords, etc. come under here. These are answers to a question.

#### Something you do

This is probably the one that is seen the least (in my experience at least). This is things that you physically do, the way you type, the way you walk, etc.

#### Somewhere you are

This is location / time based, and relies on you being in normal location at a reasonable hour to log in, ie. not in Asia and logging in at 4.30, when you live in the US.

2FA or multifactor authentication uses two or more of these categories to increase security, eg. A password and an iris scan. A smart-card and a password, etc. etc.

Yubikeys are becoming more common nowadays, and have been rolled out by Google to all their employees, although most authentication methods would fall under one of these five categories I have listed above. Time-based authentication using Tokens are also becoming more common these days.

If you have any questions leave a comment and I'll try answer as best I can.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the art for remote authentication is usage of a client certificate. It has even a legal value is some countries (France and other European countries) because it is brute force resistent, and when a certificate is delivered with correct procedures, the private key is always under the exclusive control of its recipient. In addition, a certificate can be revoked if compromissed. It is quite easy for normal use, but has 2 major drawbacks:

- correct certificate delivery is rather complex(*)
- if suffers from an egg and chicken problem: as few users have client certificates, few services offer certificate authentication, and as few services offer certificate authentication, few users are ready to pay for a serious client certificate

---

(*) the client should generate a key pair and a Certificate Signing Request (containing only the public key). Then the Authority should sign the CSR and return it to the client *in a way that ensures that it can only be delivered to the proper recipient*. The recommended way is a face to face procedure where the client shows an ID card. Ideally for a smart card, the client should then install the signed certificate on the card where the key pair was generated, or for a smartphone or personnal computer, the key pair should be generated on the device, and again only the client should install the signed certificate. Not that easy for many non tech users...

Answer (score 0):

"Passwordless" (not using a password I have to remember) methods and examples I've personally experienced:

1. Medium - in order to login to Medium, you can either do it with your social media account or sign in with email. By choosing the latter, they send you an email with an OTP link available for 15 minutes. Basically, there is no password option (only if you do it via social media but that's not a password for your Medium account).
2. Ebay - you can access your account with a temporary password that is generated by Ebay and sent to you via SMS text code. This method still relies on a 2nd device to validate your identity.

As for TypingDNA option that you mentioned, authentication with typing biometrics works on all types of texts(identical: password, credit card, etc and any text: dynamic text in a chat and so on). You could actually verify all users based on a short text like "I'm using my typing to login". Or maybe show a different text to each person. However, it's not recommended as this is only one factor.

If you don't have to protect something sensitive, then this could be an option alone. When you authenticate people by typing biometrics via the TypingDNA API, you get a match score and you can set a threshold to let people in based on your preferred level of security (also possible to balance FAR/FRR for your platform). Disclosure: I'm part of TypingDNA project